# How to reset selinux to its initial state in centos7?

Tags: centos, centos7, selinux

I am a newcomer to selinux, then I am learning selinux.

So, after a lot of operations in centos7 (I operate the selinux while learning), now I want to restore the selinux state and rule on centos7 to its initial state (just like the state and rule of seliunx when the system was just installed), so I can relearn how to operate selinux without reinstalling the linux system, is there such a method?

Answer (score 5):

Please try,

```
setenforce 0
yum remove selinux-policy\*
rm -rf /etc/selinux/targeted /etc/selinux/config
yum install selinux-policy-targeted
yum install selinux-policy-devel policycoreutils-gui  ***use this if SELinux removed by yum remove.
touch /.autorelabel; //Relabel Complete Filesystem
reboot
```

If you would like to restore only single files or files under the directory
**restorecon** command will reset the SELinux security context for files and directories to its default values

To restore the SELinux content for a file you could run

> restorecon -v filename.ext

To restore files under the current directory.

> restorecon v *

Hope this would help you. If this doesn't fix your issue, only available option is to reinstall your OS

Comment: Selinux rules were corrupted after I added some exception and it did lod with selinux. You saved me!